# Horizontal Scroll View inside LinearLayout - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have a custom list. I am trying to scroll horizontally only specific part. For Instance, in the below image iam trying to scroll horizontally just the orange box.

[image]

Here is my XML Layout: In the XML layout the Orange box starts "android:id="@+id/projected"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_img_fullcell"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Left Column -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_playerdata_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_lineup_table_row_height"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sideView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/projected"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <!-- rel 1 -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/playername1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sideView">

                <com.cbssports.nflapp.ffb.MyTextViewBold
                    android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_playerdata_playername"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#08233e"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />


            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- rel 2 -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_playerdata_playerStatsIconContainer"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playername1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_playerdata_statusIconSuspended"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_s"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sideView" >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_playerdata_playerPositionTeam"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_playerdata_startingPitcherStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_baseballgraphic"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sideView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/widget_lineup_table_status_column_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_lineup_table_row_height"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg_img_rosterpos"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <!-- <Button -->
        <com.cbssports.nflapp.ffb.VerticalTextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_playerdata_playerStatusButton"
            android:layout_width="21dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textColor="#004a8e"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="bottom|center" />
    </LinearLayout>
***<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/projected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_lineup_table_row_height"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg_img_whiteoverlay"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/percentStarted">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_player_h2h_stats_started_custom"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#333333" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/percentStarted"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_lineup_table_row_height"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg_img_whiteoverlay"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_player_projected_custom"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#333333" />
    </LinearLayout>***
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem, except the 7 warnings, can we see some logs may be or a better explanation?

Comment: I am trying to scroll horizontally the orange box. Imagine if have more values there. Right now i am having two. Suppose if have more than 5. I added HorizontalScroll View on top of <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/projected but its giving me cannot have more than one child error. Not sure how to get it working.

Comment: Ok try this: Add the `HorizontalScroll` on top of the `RelativeLayout` with this drawable "`@drawable/bkg_img_fullcell`" and try giving an unique `@+id/` to every view to distinct them. If this does not work, try wrapping the problematic views in a Layout themselves so that the `HorizontalView` will have only one child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank You g00dy, i can able to solve it by adding one LinearLayout inside horizontalScrollView it.

Here is my solution.

```
   <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:scrollbars="none">
   <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll_linear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/projected"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_lineup_table_row_height"
             android:background="@drawable/bkg_img_whiteoverlay"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/percentStarted">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_player_h2h_stats_started_custom"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#333333" />
           </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/percentStarted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_lineup_table_row_height"
            android:background="@drawable/bkg_img_whiteoverlay"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/widget_lineupview_player_projected_custom"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="#333333" />
      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also set the LinearLayout fillViewport to true and foregroundGravity to true (not sure if this last is necessary), and set the child LinearLayout gravity to right:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/IconM"
        android:id="@+id/account_food_scroll"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/client_add_button_layout"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/PadM"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/IconM"
            android:id="@+id/account_food_layout"
            android:gravity="right">
            </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```